# Find and print outliers of data using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, statistics, outliers

I want to find any outliers in a csv data table column using Pandas and Numpy. Currently I can get the the outliers on the higher end side but I'm not sure how to get the minimum outliers or the "lower" outliers if that makes sense.

Here is the function that I am using:

```
def detect_outlier(data_1):
    outliers = []
    threshold = 3
    mean_1 = np.mean(data_1)
    std_1 = np.std(data_1)

    for y in data_1:
        z_score = (y - mean_1) / std_1
        if np.abs(z_score) > threshold:
            outliers.append(y)
    return outliers
```

This returns the outliers with a z-score greater than 3(threshold) and it works. I tried changing the threshold to -3 to get the outliers on the lower spectrum but it just returns all the values of the specific column. Does that just signify that there are no lower outliers or am I doing something wrong? All the questions that I find deal with removing the outliers but I just want to display any outliers.

Also some of the outliers using the function provided for the columns return an empty array, does this signify that there are no outliers for that specific column?

The dataset is too large to post here but here is the link if it can help answer this question:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Absenteeism+at+work

Comment: Can you share a [mcve], something small to test solutions on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your outlier logic and it works on an artificial example.

Rather than checking if the *absolute value* of your z_score is *greater* than the threshold, you should check if the **raw** z_score is **less** than your threshold in this case.

See below.

```
import random
import numpy as np 

    def detect_outlier(data_1):
        outliers = []
        threshold = -3
        mean_1 = np.mean(data_1)
        std_1 = np.std(data_1)
        for y in data_1:
            z_score = (y - mean_1) / std_1
            if z_score < threshold:
                outliers.append(y)
        return outliers

data = [random.randrange(200,300,1) for i in range(1000)]
data.append(0.01)

result = detect_outlier(data)
print(f'Outlier: {result}')
```

Output:

```
Outlier: [0.01]
```

It's also possible that your dataset doesn't have extreme outliers on the negative side of the distribution, but the logic would have missed them regardless.

Comment: why not using absolute values in z_score?